# Issues With Welcome Message | Discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I have a welcome message bot which sends a welcome message every time someone joins but sometimes, it throws an error in the console saying:

```
    member.guild.channels.cache.find(ch => ch.name === "・").send(exampleEmbed).catch(e => co    nsole.error(`Welcome Error in ${message.guild.name}`) | message.channel.send("__**ERROR:**__ ** Someone joined the server but I was 
le to catch it.**"));
                                                                   ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined
```

**Code:**

```
client.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {


    const exampleEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('RANDOM')
        .setTitle(`Welcome to lovell <$, **${member.user.username}**`)
        .setImage('https://images-ext-1.discordapp.net/external/Gy-micqoX7qrlivnytbmFgfTbxPx_CSvgChFLE3qC7g/https/media.discordapp.net/attachments/755425128635957348/758525058934767617/HaxzUWa46sK5CXKzIR.gif')
        .setFooter('Boost Us');

    member.guild.channels.cache.find(ch => ch.name === "・").send(exampleEmbed).catch(e => console.error(`Welcome Error in ${message.guild.name}`) | message.channel.send("__**ERROR:**__ ** Someone joined the server but I was unable to catch it.**"));
})
```

How would I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

There is a much easier way to do what you are trying to do. Copy the ID of that channel and then get the channel in your code like this:

```
bot.on('guildMemberAdd', (member) => {
    const channel = member.guild.channels.cache.get('channel-id');
    channel.send('Welcome');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that if the channel is not found, that error occurs. The channel that wasn't found will return undefined. This code from the  [DiscordJS website](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/examples/greeting) will check if the channel exists and if it doesn't, it won't run the rest of the function.

Comment: Can i just put the channel ID?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this?:

```js
client.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
    
    let welChannel = member.guild.channels.cache.find(ch => ch.name === "・")

    const exampleEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('RANDOM')
        .setTitle(`Welcome to lovell <$, **${member.user.username}**`)
        .setImage('https://images-ext-1.discordapp.net/external/Gy-micqoX7qrlivnytbmFgfTbxPx_CSvgChFLE3qC7g/https/media.discordapp.net/attachments/755425128635957348/758525058934767617/HaxzUWa46sK5CXKzIR.gif')
        .setFooter('Boost Us');

    welChannel.send(exampleEmbed).catch(e => console.error(`Welcome Error in ${message.guild.name}`) | message.channel.send("__**ERROR:**__ ** Someone joined the server but I was unable to catch it.**"));
})
```

If this does not work, it might be that the bot cannot find the `・` channel.